# C++, two classes with mutual needs

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I have converted a scientific simulation platform from Java into C++. I have tried to keep the design as much as possible the same as previous implementation. In java because of the late binding, circular dependencies are resolved at the run time. However, circular dependencies have created a hell of a mess in C++.

1. Is there an automated tool which analyses and lists the circular includes and references? (Visual Studio 2010 only issues a huge list of nonsense errors).
2. I have tried to use forward references wherever possible. However **in some occasions both classes need functionality of the other class (i.e. call to methods which makes it impossible to use forward reference)**. These needs exist in Logic and if I radically change the design they will no more represent real world interactions.

   How could we implement two classes which need each other's methods and status? Is it possible to implement them in C++?

**Examples:**

- Example 1: I have a class called "World" which creates Objects of the type "Agent". Agent needs to call World methods to get information of its environment. World also needs to iterate through Agents and execute their "run" method and get their status (status updates may possibly be done reverse to solve this section of the problem but not the run method).
- Example 2: Agents create a collection of their "Intentions". Each Agent needs to iterate through its intentions and run/update/read intention status. Intentions also need to get information about the environment through Agent (if done directly through "World" it will create complex circles again) and also info of the Agent itself.

Below diagram shows a sub-set of classes, and some of their methods and properties:

[image: sub-set of classes, and some of their methods and properties]

Comment: If you have problems with errors, you could always post a question containing those errors (verbatim please) and someone will most likely be able to help you with it. Also, those errors may be nonsense to you, but not to someone else. It is also very hard to answer questions without seeing some code, and for this I recommend you read http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Joachim, They are the type of errors which are generated in circular dependency cases. Classes cannot be identified.
`code` 1>e:\programming\cprojt\actiondb11\actiondb\base\world.h(35): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
1>e:\programming\cprojt\actiondb11\actiondb\base\world.h(36): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Agent'
1>e:\programming\cprojt\actiondb11\actiondb\base\world.h(50): error C2065: 'Agent' : undeclared identifier

Comment: Posting the code is much more helpful than posting the errors. Posting *both* is best.

Comment: Mike, the code is near to 50,000 lines of code. I will need to cut and build a small case out of of it which reproduces the errors. Meanwhile, I did not know putting include files on top of the cpp file would solve the forward reference problem. I guess your answer will solve my problem.

Comment: Added a diagram. I hope it will help.

Comment: @wmac:  If you didn't know you needed `#include` statements, then it's time to stop hacking around and [pick up a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/241536)

Comment: @John Dibling , read my statement one more time. I said I did not know moving the include to cpp file (along with the forward reference) would solve the problem. Previously I avoided forward reference in some cases because pointers were used for calling methods and I thought using includes in the class header are the only way. Besides, I bought two books from that list and they arrived today. I am not pretending that my C++ knowledge is perfect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not seeing how forward declarations are not working for you. It looks like you need something like:

World.h:

```
#ifndef World_h
#define World_h

class Agent;

class World
{
    World();
    void AddAgent(Agent* agent) { agents.push_back(agent); }
    void RunAgents();
private:
    std::vector<Agent*> agents;
};

#endif
```

Agent.h:

```
#ifndef Agent_h
#define Agent_h

class World;
class Intention;

class Agent
{
    Agent(World& world_): world(world_) { world.AddAgent(this); }
    status_t Run();
private:
    World& world;
    std::vector<Intention*> intentions;
};

#endif
```

World.cc:

```
#include "World.h"
#include "Agent.h"

void World::RunAgents()
{
    for(std::vector<Agent*>::iterator i = agents.begin(); i != agents.end; ++i)
    {
        Agent& agent(**i);
        status_t stat = agent.Run();
        // do something with stat.
    }
}

// ...
```

Agent.cc:

```
#include "Agent.h"
#include "World.h"
#include "Intention.h"

// ...
```

Comment: I'll try forward references again with include files at the top of cpp files. i guess that would hopefully resolve problems.

Comment: Even though it's not required by the language, it's good practice to put all the includes at the start of the file so someone reading your code can quickly know its dependencies.

Comment: Is there a solution if you not only have references but actual instances of type A in Type B and vice versa? I get an "incomplete type" error from the compiler, which makes sense. But is there any way around it?

Comment: if the utter absurdity of having an `A` in a `B` and a `B` in an `A` isn't obvious, sit down and try to work out what such a thing's memory layout would look like.

Answer (score 3):

You **can** solve the problem with only forward declarations, but you probably didn't separate the implementation from the declaration of the class.

If you need to call methods from the class, a full type is needed, which is why you need to include the file. You can include the file in a `cpp` (implementation file) without worrying about circular dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Luchian. My implementation is separate but I did not move includes to the cpp files along with the forward references.